# Dom based xss example

Tags: html, xss

For a school assignment we had to make a site which is vulnerable to a dom based xss attack. We have been given very little information on it and no example.

I've used the following code in my html file:

```
Select your language:

<select><script>
    document.write("<OPTION value=1>"+document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("default=")+8)+"</OPTION>");
    document.write("<OPTION value=2>English</OPTION>");
</script></select>
```

I then fired up the site and tried appending the url using:

```
?default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

Which doesn't do anything and then again with:

```
#default=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

Which also does not do anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your console; any errors?

Comment: @EdCottrell only chrome gives an error "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://localhost:63342/Secur/index.html?name=Tim#<script>alert(42)</script>' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header." Other browsers don't give any error

Answer (score 0):

Chrome might be blocking the execution of your XSS attack, as it has a built-in filter. Most modern browsers have default XSS protection enabled. To test this, I would use Firebox, and disable the XSS filter. To do this, go to `about:config` and set the `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` value to false.

I also had to change your HTML test case. I needed to URI decode the `default` parameter in order for the script to run.

```
Select your language:

<select><script>
    document.write("<OPTION value=1>"+decodeURIComponent(document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.indexOf("default=")+8))+"</OPTION>");
    document.write("<OPTION value=2>English</OPTION>");
</script></select>
```